# Creating a matrix of arbitrary size where rows sum to 0

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, determinants

From [Creating a matrix of arbitrary size where rows sum to 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364744/creating-a-matrix-of-arbitrary-size-where-rows-sum-to-1), we can simply normalize the values by dividing each value in the matrix by the sum of all values to make sure that it sums to 1.

For example:

```
cols, rows = 5, 5
matrix = np.random.rand(rows, cols)
matrix/matrix.sum(axis=1)[:,None]
```

**How to create a matrix of arbitrary size where rows sum to 0?**

I've tried:

```
cols, rows = 5, 5
x = np.random.rand(rows, cols)
z = x - sum(sum(x)) / (rows*cols)
```

It goes to a number close to zero but never summing zero =(

Comment: I think you will never get exactly 0 due to numerical rounding errors if you're using float. One solution would be to use integers. Is there a reason you need it to be exactly 0 instead of numerically 0?

Comment: Also, in your top example, each row sums to 1 rather than the whole matrix summing to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting the average value of x from itself to create z, which will give you a matrix that sums to 0. To get the rows to sum to zero you have to subtract the average value of a row from each element in that row.

```
cols, rows = 5, 5
x = np.random.rand(rows, cols)
z = (x - np.average(x,axis=0)).T
```

This code finds the average of the columns and subtracts them as when subtracting a 1D array from a 2D array the 1D array will be subtracted from each row. This gives a matrix whose columns sum to zero, and so transposing gives a matrix whose rows sum to zero.

As Tyler Chen mentioned you won't get exactly 0 due to rounding error, but this will get you close.

I hope that helps!